# Sum across multiple sheets with criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using the formula below in my 'ALL SALES' sheet to consolidate sales from multiple sheets for a corresponding month in each sheet ... So E618 in each tab would be the sales for say Mar-22 and so on for 60 months. This has been working fine as follows
`SUM(Intl_Schedules_Start:Intl_Schedules_End!E618)`

The sheets all had Mar-22 through Feb-26 in E617 onward so summing it was simple with the above formula..
Now my sheets are more dynamic in that E617 could have Mar-23 onwards for the other 59 months in row 617 in which case when I add the cells E617 from each sheet together I am getting the wrong result as it is adding E618 from one tab which has Mar-22 in E617 and the other tab's E617 is now Mar-23 which of course is incorrect. I have been searching a way to conduct the same calculation but incorporating one criteria of matching the month value in 'ALL SALES' month column (say Mar-22) with the month in each sheets' E617 which could be different... So to summaries.. IN ALL SALES under mar-22 I need to add all the corresponding values in each tab where the month in cell C217 match
There are examples I have found on the web which require a separate list of all the tabs that are being summed but as my sheets could be moved and new ones with different names added it makes for a very time consuming task....
I anyone able to assist me in this?
I hope the image below gives a better idea
TIA
[image]

Comment: A picture would really help here.

Comment: This called [3D SUMIFS()](https://exceljet.net/formula/3d-sumif-for-multiple-worksheets).

Comment: @Scott Craner I did see the 3d Sumifs example and tried that without much success. I tried making a unique list of the tabs so I could test that formula and still no luck hence me coming here with exactly my particular issue

Comment: @findwindow.. Many thanks.. I have added an image.. hope it makes sense :(

Comment: Can you post your attempt with the 3d sumifs?

Comment: @Scott Craner. My attempt produces a #Name error ```=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&Intl_Schedules_Start:Intl_Schedules_End&"'!AR1"),C2,INDIRECT("'"&Intl_Schedules_Start:Intl_Schedules_End&"'!E618")))``` In this example AR1 represents Mar-22 (I did not test it in its exact location as need to preserve that info until I had the formula right

Comment: `Intl_Schedules_Start:Intl_Schedules_End` needs to be the range that contains the list of worksheets.  You cannot use the `Intl_Schedules_Start:Intl_Schedules_End` method with SUMIFS like you did with SUM.

Comment: Ah.. Thanks Scott.. I had tried that with a unique list I generated from another sheet just to give me that range to test with but it wont work practically as there would be too much VBA involved to change that list each time my tabs change- There could be up to 40 which change as our schedule changes. My version of excel 2016  is already complaining and hanging each time i run VBA so wanted to stick to a formula if possible

Answer (score 0):

Based on the formula you give within the comments:

`=SUM(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",0,Intl_Schedules_Start:Intl_Schedules_End!AR1,Intl_Schedules_Start:Intl_Schedules_End!E618)&"</b></a>","//b[preceding::*["&SHEETS(Intl_Schedules_Start:Intl_Schedules_End!E618)&"]="""&C2&"""]"))`

This could be abbreviated using `LET` if desired.

Comment: Many thanks Jos..  I have to admit but I don't understand the formula. I placed it in a real location using correct dates and cell references however still getting a #Name? error. Running the Evaluate Formula tool it fails at the "Intl_Schedules_Start:Intl_Schedules_End" part

Comment: Hi Gary. What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: Jos I am working on Excel 2016

Comment: Ah, `TEXTJOIN` is not available in that version, apologies.

Comment: No worries Jon. I appreciate you taking time though...